# How to open pdf inside ionic app without download option or using inappbrowser without allow user to download

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have done one app which will show the pdf file using an in-app browser which working good in both android and ios. But my client needs that pdf file should not be download for the user. So is there any other method to show pdf file for preview alone.

I heard about iframe but not able to get any example code of how it will work.please help me out.

```
<form class="list cls0Padding" >
        <div class="item item-body cls0Padding cls0Border">
            <div class="row cls0Padding">
                <div  class="col col-50 clsGrid"  href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
                    <div class="clsGridOverlay"><span class="clsGridTitle">PDF</span></div>
                </div>
                <div  class="col col-50 clsGrid" href="#" ng-click="playVideo()">
                    <div class="clsGridOverlay"><span class="clsGridTitle"> VIDEOS</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My controller :

```
  $window.OpenLink = function(link) {
    window.open( link, '_system');
  };
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

install `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`
 In case of android we use GoogleDocs to open pdf file as by default android browser does not support pdf viewing. iOS is smart enough to handle pdf itself as usual smile .

Example :

```
$scope.view_link = function (url, link_type) {
            if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
                if (link_type !== undefined && link_type !== null) {
                    if (link_type.toLowerCase() !== 'html') {
                        url = 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
                    }
                }
            }
            var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');
        }
```

for more https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/8ce6b497fa803936784629187e9c66ebaddfbe1b/doc/index.md

if you are looking for `iframe` try something like this

```
<iframe ng-src="{{pdfurl}}" style="width:100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

in controller..

```
$scope.pdfurl =$sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.pdf));
```

Comment: oh you here thanks alot. But my client asking without download the pdf. its just for preview alone.So by using inappbrowser already that i have installed. can i make that without download

Comment: But using iframe how can i handle the onclick functionality. Bec i have two grid view and if i press on grid then my pdf will open. please see my update code

Comment: so by my updated code how can i handle the iframe to open my pdf without download

Answer (score 0):

I suspect to view the actual PDF it would need to be downloaded.
Other ways to display the PDF would be to rasterise the PDF on the server (convert each page to an image) and create a viewer to view the images.

Comment: does iframe will make as per i need to show pdf file without download ?

Comment: an iframe effectively a browser within a browser, so the same rules will apply.

Comment: can you please help me , how can i conver the pdf to imahe and to display. i am struck with more than 3 days. Not able to find solutions